# Oracle SQL Developer with no Database

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies if this has been asked before - I couldn't find anything online.

I have some data in a couple of Excel spreadsheets that I need to clean, join, process etc. I would like to do this using SQL as the language is intuitive and easy to use. I currently have access to Oracle SQL Developer through my work computer, but it's not connected to any databases and I won't be able to do so for a while. I know that if I did have access to a database, I could simply upload the tables there, and then start working with them that way. Given that is not an option, I was wondering if there is anyway for me to create a local database just on my machine that I can upload those tables to and work with them that way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Certainly. Go to Oracle Technology Network, download and install [18c Express Edition](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html) (XE). It is a lightweight database, fully operational and free to use. Make sure to read & follow installation guide.

Alternatively, go to [apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/en/) and register (also for free). You'll get access to a database and the latest Application Express (Apex). Using its wizard, it is simple to create an **application** which will let you upload your files and work on them.

Also, there's [Oracle Cloud Free Tier](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/).

What would I do, if I were you? Install XE, probably.

Comment: would you recommend Oracles [vagrant boxes](https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-projects) or the [prebuilt developer VM](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html)?

Comment: I've never used any of those, @wolφi, but yes - thank you for mentioning them. Honestly, I've never even heard of *vagrant boxes*, but I know about Virtual Box machines; forgot to mention them as an option.

Comment: You could download a docker image as well. I did that a while ago, worked like a charm and there is plenty of information/blogs on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically some of these other answers could work, but it sounds like you're working this as part of your job so you need to confirm a couple of things with your employer before diving in:

1. Most employers limit your ability to install software on your workstation or laptop. Oracle XE requires administrator privileges, so you need to confirm that your company will allow you to have that, and that they are ok with a database service running on a personal workstation. Many are *not* ok with that. Case in point: I do testing on my company laptop for various proof-of-concept things, but I'm not allowed to have admin privileges. I got special permission to install Oracle VirtualBox so I can work with some VMs, but that's it.
2. Given that you are working with company data, they may not be ok with you exporting that to a cloud service that they are not paying for (i.e. outside of their security boundary and legal oversight). If you plan to go that route, you need to make sure the company is ok with that approach too. My guess would be "not so much."
3. As far as creating a local database, you can't do that with Oracle without installing the software, which requires admin privileges. Also as I mentioned many companies have issues with installing software that creates network services (i.e. any database) on personal workstations because of the security implications.

Whatever you decide, just be sure what you're doing is *legal* with the powers that be.